# Akka Stream return object from Sink

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I've got a `SourceQueue`. When I offer an element to this I want it to pass through the `Stream` and when it reaches the `Sink` have the output returned to the code that offered this element (similar as `Sink.head` returns an element to the `RunnableGraph.run()` call).

How do I achieve this? A simple example of my problem would be:

```
val source = Source.queue[String](100, OverflowStrategy.fail)
val flow = Flow[String].map(element => s"Modified $element")
val sink = Sink.ReturnTheStringSomehow
val graph = source.via(flow).to(sink).run()

val x = graph.offer("foo")
println(x) // Output should be "Modified foo"
val y = graph.offer("bar")
println(y) // Output should be "Modified bar"
val z = graph.offer("baz")
println(z) // Output should be "Modified baz"
```

**Edit:** For the example I have given in this question **Vladimir Matveev** provided the best answer. However, it should be noted that this solution only works if the elements are going into the `sink` in the same order they were offered to the `source`. If this cannot be guaranteed the order of the elements in the `sink` may differ and the outcome might be different from what is expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it is simpler to use the already existing primitive for pulling values from a stream, called [`Sink.queue`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink$@queue[T]():akka.stream.scaladsl.Sink[T,akka.stream.scaladsl.SinkQueueWithCancel[T]]). Here is an example:

```
val source = Source.queue[String](128, OverflowStrategy.fail)
val flow = Flow[String].map(element => s"Modified $element")
val sink = Sink.queue[String]().withAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(1, 1))

val (sourceQueue, sinkQueue) = source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()

def getNext: String = Await.result(sinkQueue.pull(), 1.second).get

sourceQueue.offer("foo")
println(getNext)

sourceQueue.offer("bar")
println(getNext)

sourceQueue.offer("baz")
println(getNext)
```

It does exactly what you want.

Note that setting the `inputBuffer` attribute for the queue sink may or may not be important for your use case - if you don't set it, the buffer will be zero-sized and the data won't flow through the stream until you invoke the `pull()` method on the sink.

`sinkQueue.pull()` yields a `Future[Option[T]]`, which will be completed successfully with `Some` if the sink receives an element or with a failure if the stream fails. If the stream completes normally, it will be completed with `None`. In this particular example I'm ignoring this by using `Option.get` but you would probably want to add custom logic to handle this case.

Comment: That's cool and it works fine with my example. However, in my actual code I'm using a `Stream` to handle `HttpRequests`. The `flow` forks into multiple substreams and gets merged back again. Some of substreams will be faster than others and using the `Sink` as a `queue` makes me think that I cannot guarantee that a requests will end up with correct response.

Comment: Well, according to your examples and description, you want to push a value to the source queue and afterwards get it back from the sink, synchronously. As long as you're following the "push the input - pull the output" pattern, you may be sure that you process the responses in the correct order. But even if your access pattern is different (and it would be nice if it was reflected in the question), the simplest way to correlate the request with the response is to pass the request along with the transformed value in a tuple.

Comment: You're right, I failed to mention this in my description. You're answer is the best answer to this question.

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know about `Sink.queue`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you know what `offer()` method returns if you take a look at its definition :) What you can do is to create `Source.queue[(Promise[String], String)]`, create helper function that pushes pair to stream via `offer`, make sure `offer` doesn't fail because queue might be  full, then complete promise inside your stream and use future of the promise to catch completion event in external code.

I do that to throttle rate to external API used from multiple places of  my project.

Here is how it looked in my project before Typesafe added Hub sources to akka

```
import scala.concurrent.Promise
import scala.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedDeque

import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}
import akka.stream.{OverflowStrategy, QueueOfferResult}

import scala.util.Success

private val queue = Source.queue[(Promise[String], String)](100, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
  .toMat(Sink.foreach({ case (p, param) =>
      p.complete(Success(param.reverse))
  }))(Keep.left)
  .run

private val futureDeque = new ConcurrentLinkedDeque[Future[String]]()

private def sendQueuedRequest(request: String): Future[String] = {

  val p = Promise[String]

  val offerFuture = queue.offer(p -> request)

  def addToQueue(future: Future[String]): Future[String] = {
    futureDeque.addLast(future)
    future.onComplete(_ => futureDeque.remove(future))
    future
  }

  offerFuture.flatMap {
    case QueueOfferResult.Enqueued =>
      addToQueue(p.future)
  }.recoverWith {
    case ex =>
      val first = futureDeque.pollFirst()
      if (first != null)
        addToQueue(first.flatMap(_ => sendQueuedRequest(request)))
      else
        sendQueuedRequest(request)
  }
}
```

I realize that blocking synchronized queue may be bottleneck and may grow indefinitely but because API calls in my project are made only from other akka streams which are backpressured I never have more than dozen items in `futureDeque`. Your situation may differ.

If you create `MergeHub.source[(Promise[String], String)]()` instead you'll get reusable sink. Thus every time you need to process item you'll create complete graph and run it. In that case you won't need hacky java container to queue requests.

Comment: This is brilliant. I hadn't thought of using an `Promise`. Could you elaborate on the helper function though? I dont understand what you mean by this.